# "Authorization failed" with SVN 1.5.2 on OS X (PowerPC G4)

Tags: svn, macos, collabnet

I'm trying to commit to an SVN server hosted on my school's network. I have installed SVN 1.5.2 with binaries downloaded from CollabNet [here](http://www.collab.net/downloads/community/). The error reported is:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: MKACTIVITY of '/opensvn/cs598r/!svn/act/defe271c-f33b-4851-a706-b2906301fed0': authorization failed (http://dna.cs.byu.edu)
```

That's the complete error message - nowhere does it say 403 Forbidden. I have tried deleting my working copy and checking it out again to no avail. I have checked and double-checked that my password and permissions are correct on the server. I have checked that the URL is correct. I can successfully commit from a remote machine, but not from mine. Other members of my team are able to commit from their computers, but when they try from mine, they get the same error. One of the other members of my team is using 1.5.1 CollabNet binaries with no trouble. What about my client is broken?

Comment: Can you confirm with your schools sys admin that you are authorized to write to the repository? This may be the case if you are able to read from the repository (check out) but not to write (commit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can commit from other machines, and your team members can commit but not from your machine, I'd say it's probably an issue with your subversion client.  I'd suggest you uninstall the client you have, then install the version that's being run on the server just to be safe.

Comment: It's time to just do a wipe an install. Thanks for all your help, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think **authorization** is required for you to commit your local copy...

or

Maybe you can commit, but the server is not auto updating? ...try updating the server after committing your work through **SSH** and **SVN update**

Answer (score 0):

Not all forms of accessing a repository allow all forms of access.  If you checked out your code via a read-only method, you won't be able to commit.  As an example, it isn't uncommon for a WebDav repository to allow only anonymous checkout on http://... and allow authentication and commits only on https://...

Check that the repository you are checking out from is letter-for-letter identical to the repositories that the other members of your team are checking out from.

Comment: I just deleted my working copy, copied the URL from the source on our Google group again, checked it out, still can't commit. I SSH'd into a remote machine, used the same URL, and successfully committed. It's a local problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the [proper CAPS for the entire svn url](http://www.alagad.com/go/blog-entry/subversion-mkactivity-and-403-forbidden-headaches)

Comment: Checked as per the previous two answers, and the URL is correct. I can commit on a remote machine, but not on mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is within the parentheses (http://dna.cs.byu.edu).  You can often checkout with the http path, but commits usually want https.